# Akka http: Is it possible to use protostuff in akka-http marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, akka-http, protostuff

I need to transfer instances of a class with a single field which is a Map[String, AnyRef] over wire.

And I have issues to construct marshaller and unmarshaller to do the work, However I can serialize and deserialize instances of the class using protostuff.

So my question is:
is it possible to use protostuff in akka-http to compose a unmarshaller and how to do that if it's possible?

Comment: you can implement your custom marshaler.

Comment: I will try to read the akka manuals and get it done, and If you can give me an example, it will be appreciated.